# Recuperar dados no banco de dados por checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boa tarde

Estou tendo dificuldades em recuperar os dados no banco de dados via checkbox.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form action="resultado.php" multiple method="post">
            <h3>Bairros</h3>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" value="Bairro de Fátima"/>Bairro de Fátima</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" value="Benfica"/>Benfica</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" value="Caju"/>Caju</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" value="Catumbi"/>Catumbi</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" value="Centro"/>Centro</p>

            <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="Enviar"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
        </form>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual a sua dificuldade exatamente? não está claro

Comment: Por exemplo, ao escolher uma ou mais opções no checkbox, retornar o valor das caixas que foram selecionadas via mysqli no caso um SELECT * FROM <tabela>, mas, associado ao que foi marcado no checkbox

Comment: uma consulta mais ou menso desse tipo: select *
from <tabela>
where bairro='xyz' and categoria='Saúde' and orgao='Municipal'

Comment: Tu faz isso assim.Procure saber sobre a função each do jquery juntamente com (:checked) ela ira os dados campos selecionados pra você.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function(){
$( "#enviar" ).click(function() {



$("input[type=checkbox][name='bairro[]']:checked").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
  
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<h3>Bairros</h3>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" value="Bairro de Fátima"/>Bairro de Fátima</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" value="Benfica"/>Benfica</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" value="Caju"/>Caju</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" value="Catumbi"/>Catumbi</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" value="Centro"/>Centro</p>

<input type="hidden"  name="acao" value="Enviar"/>
<input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Enviar"/>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ou vc pode usar post ou get para pegar os dados usando FORM.Agora vc pega esses dados joga no select e faz uma comparação usando o where ..